# Why C++ uses pointer for next node in linked list, but langauges like C# or Java use just the name of the class Node?

Tags: java, c#, c++, pointers, data-structures

Most of the linked list implementations in C++ are like this, a pointer reference will be used as the type for the "next" node

```cpp
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
}
```

But for languages like C#, Java and Python, why pointer is is not directly used? I could see only this kind of implementation:

```cs
// C#
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
}
```

```java
// Java
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
}
```

What is the underlying difference? Ofcourse Java doesn't support pointers, but what about c#?

Comment: Because those are *completely* different languages. See [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), perhaps it will enlighten you a bit on how Java understands objects.

Comment: Because they are all *different* languages, wich different riles and semantics? Like some languages defaults to using *references* and don't need pointers in the same way?

Comment: Fundamentally I think you should understand "managed" vs "native" code. That will shed some light on those specific differences.

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes need take a deep dive into this!

Comment: There are no pointers in Java, but for all non-trivial types, references are always used. Since `Node` is an object, any variable of type `Node` actually holds a reference (or equivalently, a pointer) to a node. Since this is implicit in the language, and is the only way you can refer to objects in Java, you don't need to specify it syntactically with a `*` or `&` to distinguish it from an object directly created on the stack, as you would in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the posted answers and other stackoverflow stuffs related to references and pointers like this one [C++ references Vs C# references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919855/c-references-vs-c-sharp-references)

This is what Makes more sense to me,

- C# References are Managed references. But in C++ there is no such
  manged environment hence we need to allocate and carefully
  de-allocate the memory. In C# this will be manged automatically by
  GC. So it is recommended to use references where ever possible rather
  than directly using pointers.
- Similar to C++ Pointers, C# can also hold nulls.  C++ pointers hold
  address of a memory location, C# References holds the address of
  another object in the memory.
- In C# we can use pointers only under unsafe scope, and in java there is no such pointer concepts.

Taking all this into account we can use references rather than pointers for programming languages that execute in a managed environment.

Feel free to edit if this answer can be further improved!

Answer (score 3):

CPP"s `Node*` is equivalent to java's `Node`, and I'm pretty sure C#'s `Node` as well. In java, all primitives are the direct value. The primitives are `int`, `long`, `short`, `byte`, `char`, `double`, `float`, and `boolean`. These are passed directly, by value: If you call a method passing `5`, 5 is pushed onto the stack. If the method you invoke changes their value, the caller can't tell.

But aside from that hardcoded list of primitives, all other types are called **references** which is just java-ese for **pointers** - except in java, you can't do pointer arithmatic. at all. You can't ask for 'the memory location 5 higher than where-ever this object lives', like you can do in C.

Here's a trivial example:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Hello!");
        System.out.println(list);
        example1(list);
        System.out.println(list);
        example2(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    static void example1(List<String> in) {
        list.add("World!");
    }

    static void example2(List<String> in) {
        in = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.add("Bye!");
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
[Hello!]
[Hello!, World!]
[Hello!, World!]
```

example1 never changes the variable (The reference), it merely 'dereferences it' (follows the pointer), thus the changes you make are observed in the caller.

But example2 has no effect on main's list variable: It reassigns the variable (makes a new object and then updates its reference to point at this new object). example1's list doesn't change; its pointer doesn't change.

It's like treasure maps: Everybody has a copy of the treasure map, but not of the treasure. `in.add` is like: "Follow the map, open the treasure chest, put a new item in". `in = new ArrayList` is: "Make a new treasure chest, bury it in the sand, wipe out this treasure map, and now write the location of this newly buried treasure chest on it". If I have a *copy* of your map, if you follow your copy and add to the treasure then I'll see that if I later follow my map. But if you make an entirely new map, then whatever you do to the treasure at your new location is never going to be noticed by me.

This matches C++'s behaviour.... at least, for `Node*`. Not for `Node`.

Comment: In C#, a [`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) is also a direct *value type*, with value semantics.  Here's nice graph of the [type hierarchy](https://medium.com/@suemayah.eldursi/c-types-b3cd52ba2c0a).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the underlying difference?

Probably none at all. At the machine-code level, each node contains the address of the next node in the chain.

The question is, rather, about how languages represent objects in source code. Is a variable declaration written as `Foo bar` (for example) going to be an actual instance of the type `Foo` or is it going to be a way to get at (handle, pointer, reference) the actual instance.  If it's the actual instance, your language probably also needs some syntax to describe not-the-instance but way-to-get-at-the-instance.  Perhaps more than one way (`Foo*`, `Foo&` in C++).

The possibility of different approaches is one reason why we have different programming languages.